# Stepping down as moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

The time has come for me to step down and put my diamond aside. I have had the privilege of being an elected moderator on Ask Ubuntu since June 2016. I have enjoyed it immensely, but I am afraid the [current state](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/203101) of the SE network means I just can't continue.

Until yesterday, I was a moderator on three sites of the network. I no longer feel I can do this. I just don't believe in the company behind these sites anymore, in fact, I actively fear it. I felt that being a multi-site mod required me to be more involved with SE than I am now comfortable being.

I love the communities I belong to and I really don't want to abandon them, but I just can't be a multi-site mod any more. It feels too much like an endorsement of SE. I have therefore put down two of my three diamonds and have only stayed on as a moderator of Unix & Linux, which was my first home on the SE network. This was a difficult choice since I am also very attached to the very fine community here at AU, but I just couldn't keep more than one diamond. I don't even know how long I'll manage to stay on at U&L.

Being a moderator for sites controlled by a company so unethical as to [publicly attack](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/01/stack_exchange_controversy/) one of its own volunteer moderators in the press is very stressful. I don't want to rehash all of the ways SE has failed us in the past year, those interested can read the link in the first paragraph (and links therein). Suffice it to say that while I used to feel that SE had my back and would protect me, I now feel I need to protect myself and my communities from SE. While I used to feel that SE actually cared and honestly tried to be ethical, now I feel they don't give a crap about anything but the bottom line.

Feeling like this about the company behind the sites, I just can't be a moderator for multiple stacks anymore. It's taking too much out of me. So, I wold like to thank all of you, first for the trust you showed me in electing me in the first place and for being the wonderful community that you've been all these years. I leave you in the very capable hands of the remaining moderator team and I'll be seeing you around on the site!

Comment: I tip my hat to you, @terdon; you've been quite an exemplary model of a moderator during my time serving, always maintaining a respectful and eager-to-learn air, and willing to stand up for what you think is right. Other moderators could take a leaf out of your book. It's quite unfortunate that things have come to this point for all of us.

Comment: Thanks @user58, that means a lot coming from you. I feel very much the same about your tenure.

Comment: Thanks for everything!

Comment: Oh wow. Never forget our first encounter on this question https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8768/72216 when I was a greeny, and you were no mod yet. We might have our disagreements once in a while, but man, you are one of the most dedicated mods. Hate to see you step down, but fully agree with the reasons why. See you around. Many thanks for all your effort.

Comment: :( :( yeah. Thank you for your works and efforts

Comment: Thanks, you've been a great mod!

Comment: This whole sad drama initiated but not corrected by SE should give pause to anyone considering becoming a moderator.

Comment: [Warning potential new moderators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337941/629261)

Comment: Of all the moderators that I've seen over the years across all sites, you had most of my respect. Thank you for the gargantuan amount of work you've done in the moderator role for this site and SE as whole !

Answer (score 21):

Sorry to see you go. Although I respect your decision but I'll surely miss bothering you in room no. 201 every once in a while. Thank you for all the support you have given as a mod. Peace ☮️.

Comment: Well, you can still do so, I'll be around :)

Answer (score 16):

We will miss you. Do hang out in the chatroom!

Comment: Dont' worry, I plan to :)

Answer (score 8):

I have to admit I had a hard time up-voting your resignation message as I find it sad to see you go. But I guess I can not change your mind in this matter being a mod on Ask Ubuntu even tho you where a good choice and you brought this way the U&L and Ask Ubuntu community closer together.

I still hope you will continue to hang out in chat and for the matter of being a mod, well, so long and thanks for all the fish.